# When screen is off, camera preview in background comes to error

Tags: android, android-camera2

Code base on GoogleSamples, and change somethings for preview in background instead of take picture in the sample code.

**For Example:**

```
     @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*startBackgroundThread();

        // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
        // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
        // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
        // the SurfaceTextureListener).
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        /*closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();*/
        super.onPause();
    }

   public synchronized void start() {
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            return;
        }
        startBackgroundThread();

        // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
        // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
        // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
        // the SurfaceTextureListener).
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (mCameraDevice == null) {
            return;
        }
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }
```

But, when screen if off for a minute, camera preview comes to a error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLUB6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19S3d.png)

Why and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startForegroundService(new Intent(this, EmptyService.class));

A foreground service is need int the activity, and then all is Ok.